# How to check if a certain hard fork is enabled in your network?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, network, proof-of-work, hardforks

We are running a private PoW (Proof of Work) network on geth

I would like to know, how can i determine if a certain hard fork is enabled on my network ?

For instance, how will i check if the London Hard Fork is enabled on my private network